# I want to make a snake game in a C# console, movement problem

Tags: c#, if-statement, controls, key, readkey

To change snakes direction I first have to press upArrow and then the new direction of the snake, and the snake is going in that direction until I hit upArrow again. So, to change direction to the left you need to press upArrow and then leftArrow. I want that to disappear, when I press left to make snake go left. Basically up arrow is pausing the game and I dont know why.

```
            if (Console.KeyAvailable && Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
            {
                keyinfo = Console.ReadKey();
                Console.WriteLine(ConsoleKey.UpArrow);
            }
            if (Console.KeyAvailable && Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow)
            {
                keyinfo = Console.ReadKey();
                Console.WriteLine(ConsoleKey.DownArrow);
            }
            if (Console.KeyAvailable && Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow)
            {
                keyinfo = Console.ReadKey();
                Console.WriteLine(ConsoleKey.LeftArrow);
            }
            if (Console.KeyAvailable && Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow)
            {
                keyinfo = Console.ReadKey();
                Console.WriteLine(ConsoleKey.RightArrow);
            }
            if (keyinfo.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
            {
                j--;
            }
            if (keyinfo.Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow)
            {
                j++;
            }
            if (keyinfo.Key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow)
            {
                k--;
            }
            if (keyinfo.Key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow)
            {
                k++;
            }
```

Comment: I think part of the issue might be that you are performing a `ReadKey` in the if statement (which I assume means that key press has been actioned). You are then performing another `ReadKey()`which would be the left key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `ReadKey` too many times.  You should call it once and then store the result in a variable:

```
     if (Console.KeyAvailable)
     {
          keyinfo = Console.ReadKey(true);
          Console.WriteLine(keyinfo);

          if (keyinfo.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
          {
              j--;
          }
          if (keyinfo.Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow)
          {
              j++;
          }
          if (keyinfo.Key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow)
          {
              k--;
          }
          if (keyinfo.Key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow)
          {
              k++;
          }
     }
```

Comment: My new code isn't the same as yours but it helped me to solve it. I'll post my code below.

Answer (score 0):

```
            if (Console.KeyAvailable)
            {
                keyinfo = Console.ReadKey(true);
                Console.WriteLine(keyinfo);

            }
            if (keyinfo.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
            {
                j--;
            }
            if (keyinfo.Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow)
            {
                j++;
            }
            if (keyinfo.Key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow)
            {
                k--;
            }
            if (keyinfo.Key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow)
            {
                k++;
            }
```